# How to build a Wordpress website with Elementor in a team?

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

My team and I are currently developing WordPress using Elementor as the theme builder. Every member of the team will use their laptop/PC to develop. Because we using Elementor, any changes that occur will immediately change the data in our database. If we just upload our database to the server, obviously it will keep overwriting previous changes. Is there any best practice to develop WordPress using Elementor in order to avoid this kind of risk?

Thank you guys :)

Comment: If you want to practise, why not use distinct instances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you work directly online with several administrators? If someone is modifying a page, Wordpress will ask you if you want to take the lead on it (and overwrite previous changes from your colleagues)

Moreover, you can still define draft pages so you won't affect the live website and then, when it is ready, you can switch for the new page!

Comment: That is a good solution. I just wonder if there are any plugins that have tools like dump-db-structure as Drupal has, but it will also dump the content (and give it a version). But still I will discuss your idea with my team. Thanks a lot! @Charly